# FaceBook Requests retrieving custom data using PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I have read, in the [facebook example guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas-games/requests/#step2), that I can send custom data with a request.

Following the example I have sent a request w/ the 'data' parameter in JS.

```
var challengeData = {"challenge_score" : gScore};

FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
  title: 'Friend Smash Challenge!',
  message: 'I just smashed ' + gScore + ' friends! Can you beat it?',
  data: challengeData
}, fbCallback);
```

I think that this part is fine, but now I can't understand how to retrieve this data in PHP.

I have tried with:

```
$facebook->api("/$requestId");
```

and

```
$facebook->api("/$requestId?fields=data");
```

*(**$requestId** is the id of my request)*

but data isn't there.

Someone know how to do this? Are days that I try to figure out, but I haven't any clue :-(

Thanks.

Comment: I think you have to use the individual user request object, `<request_object_id>_<user_id>` to get access to `data`.

Comment: I think the solution lies on the same page that you shared! Check out [this part](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/canvas-games/requests/#step4).

Comment: @CBroe unfortunately `<request_object_id>_<user_id>` is for deleting a request.

@RahilArora I have read: "You can then extract the request_ids and create an HTTP GET request to the Open Graph using the Facebook SDK convenience method FB.api. You are requesting from the path https://graph.facebook.com/REQUEST_ID."
But this is what I'm doing with `$facebook->api("/$requestId");` , no?

Comment: _“unfortunately <request_object_id>_<user_id> is for deleting a request”_ – nope, it’s also for requesting details. It depends on the _method_ you use.

Answer (score 0):

When you fetch whole request data with request id by using Facebook API, You can use extra data that you've attached to your app request.

```
<?
$response = $facebook->api("/$requestId");
$data = json_decode($response['data']);
var_dump($data);
```